# How to list all possible configuration options for an Azure service

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, settings

I wonder if there is a way to use AZ CLI to see all available configuration options for a specific  Azure service.
The purpose is to be able to secure that we have configured everything correctly. And to be able to question why certain configuration options has not been configured properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`az resource show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-show) command, in general, you can find the `Resource ID` in your resource in the portal -> `Properties`(not exclude some properties of some specific resources cannot be modified, it depends on the specific case).

```
az resource show --ids <Resource ID of your azure resource>
```

For example, you could use the command for a web app, the `properties` are all returned.

```
az resource show --ids /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<grouo-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/joywebapp1
```

[image]

---

Besides, if you want to set the properties, you could use [`az resource update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-update), sample as below.

```
az resource update --ids $id --set properties.connectionType=Proxy
```

Comment: @TyngdPunkt Glad to hear that.;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to see all the configuration options for a particular command. [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/interactive-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) has something named Interactive mode which let you to see the available commands and options.

Comment: I want to see all settings that are available for a service. My purpose is mainly from a security perspective. If we take AzureSQL as one example. There i know I can enable "threat detection", I know I can configure the PaaS Firewall etc.. How can i list all available settings for a service from AZ CLI.

Comment: you have use Tab to see all the available options or use az help.

Comment: Is it possible to show a JSON configuration file for each service where we can see what options has been configured?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-configuration?view=azure-cli-latest